# Junit with spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, junit, spring-boot

I have an application designed with spring boot and hibernate completed. Now I want to use Junit for unit testing. What should be included in application.properties and do we need a separate Java file for testing? Any working example or docs that would help me to getting started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include following dependency and spring boot will configure itself for testing.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

after that you should be able to run your tests from src/test/java.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

For Data Layer tests use @Transactional over method or Class. You may create a separate Test class by extending main test class. See below for more options

```
@Transactional
public class DataLayerTest extends ApplicationTests{

    @Autowired
    private LeaveDaoImpl daoImpl;

    @Test
    // @Transactional 
    // @Rollback(true)
    public void testFindall() {
        // you test here
    }    
}
```

Comment: The Test report when i include the DataLayerTest as a class :

`Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.053 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.test.DataLayerTest
testFindall(org.test.DataLayerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context [DefaultTestContext@8e24743 testClass = DataLayerTest, testInstance = org.test.DataLayerTest@39d76cb5, testMethod = testFindall@DataLayerTest, testException = [null]`

Comment: Well I assumed you are using Spring Transaction Management in you service/data layer. At this point without knowing any further details it will be hard to figure out that is wrong. See Spring reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html